# Expanding row value into induvidual row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need some help with a SQL Query. I know this should be redesigned, but it is a small fix I am doing on a larger system :(.

The system has a table called sales, containing parts sold.

```
id  | date   | idpart
1   |unixtime|   227
2   |unixtime|   256
```

And so on..

In the table Orderdetails, containing the content of the order, the parts are listed by id, and with the amount a unique part is ordered by a customer.

```
id |idpart | amount
1  | 255   | 4
2  | 265   | 2
```

Now, my problem is that I have to run a Query to populate the sales table but adding the idpart as a new row for the same amount of times the part has as amountvalue in order.
I need result to be:

```
id  | date   | idpart
1   |unixtime|   227
2   |unixtime|   256 

3   |unixtime|   255
4   |unixtime|   255
5   |unixtime|   255
6   |unixtime|   255
7   |unixtime|   265
8   |unixtime|   265
```

Is there anyone who could give me some help on this problem?.

Comment: They need each part listed a single time in the sales table. System is designed like that, some reports running on top of sales has to have data in that fasion. :(

Comment: Cant u do the duplication logic from the application?

Comment: I dont have access to that part of the application yet. Earlier they had the amount column in the sales table aswell. But hey have for some reason removed it, and now it stopped working.. Who would believe!!

Comment: I would say convince the team that deal with application logic to handle it, would be much easier and faster to do from application.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you on that. Problem is that could take weeks. I just need to generate the sales table for the analysts. Right now i have 60K rows in the Orderdetails that i need to populate into sales :( This kind of SQL is not my strong suit, so i would very much appreciate a heads up on how to solve it...

Comment: I can imagine a solution that uses a stored procedure to accomplish this. It seems like overkill though.

Comment: I was hoping for some SQL query that would expand the Orderdetails row into the amount of times each part needs to be added to sales. Of course i could solve this in code, reading the amount and running a SQL query for each idpart the amount of times its listed. But i would rather add code to the solution to populate the sales table each time an order is ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy if you have a table with numbers.  You can do it as:

```
select id, date, idpart
from sales
union all
select id, date, idpart
from orders o cross
     numbers n
     on n.number <= o.amount
```

This is assuming that `date` is coming from the orders table.

Now, you just need to generate the numbers table.  This is a pain in MySQL.  Perhaps you have another table you can use, such as a calendar table.  Otherwise, you can create one by inserting into a table with an auto increment column.

In other databases, you can use the `row_number()` function to create such a table on the fly.  But MySQL does not support this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately date does not exist in the order table :( And as far as i know the UNION operator requires the column set to be the same on the tables used for UNION..